# React setInteval --Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node

Tags: reactjs

i am using setInterval Api of javascript with useState in `react` , sometimes i am getting this issue and it breaks the whole App.

```
 const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(30);
  useEffect(() => {
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    };
  });
```

Comment: You'd have to share full code to better udnerstand. Your code looks OK (i mean it should work somehow..), but has flaws: you did not specified dependency array, which most probably should be empty array `[]` , as you would want to start timer when your component is mounted (becomes "visible").

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that You haven't specified the dependency array.
Always remember one thing, **when you don't specify the dependency array of useEffect it becomes simple code** like this :

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(30);
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
```

On Every state change, this function is rerendering. that's the issue.

**Solution:**

```
const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(30);
  useEffect(() => {
    let myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1);
      }
    }, 1000);
    return () => {
      clearInterval(myInterval);
    };
  },[seconds]);
```